# DesktopAppConverter worked but I get a "the parameter is incorrect" error running the app

Tags: windows, mfc, windows-store, desktop-app-converter

I ran the DesktopAppConverter and was successful at getting an appx file for my desktop program. It was unsigned so I opted to use powershell to install it like this:

```
Add-AppxPackage -Path .\AppxManifest.xml -Register
```

This worked but if I try to run the app that got installed, Windows gives me the following error message and nothing more:

> The parameter is incorrect.

Any idea what the error might mean in this context?

My desktop program uses directx and also some VFW stuff but no .net because it's all old-school MFC stuff.